# Unable to log in (Firefox 15.0.1)

Tags: support, bug, firefox

Today my profile page didn't recognize me. I didn't succeed to log in using Firefox 15.0.1 and a portable computer.

1. After clicking "login" a refresh message appeared
   $$$$
   [image]
2. After a few seconds the message changed to "You are being redirected ..." 
   $$$$
   [image]
3. Then the 2nd message disappeared and my profile page didn't recognize me.

This post was typed in the same portable computer but in Google Chrome.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with Firefox 17.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today this problem is solved. I don't know what has happed.

Comment: Having these issues now.